# About Nikkah and arranged marriage

Tags: nikah

I am being forced to marry someone who is marrying me for wrong reasons and according to our traditions and understandings refusal of nikkah is very difficult.
What is the advisable Islamic way to refuse?

Comment: Saying no is not an option?

Comment: I need references from Islamic hadith or Quran relating to forced marriage so I can show others?

Comment: You could look here: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/60/woman146s-right-to-refuse-marriage-to-someone

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,

Explain to your parents that a nikah is valid from Islamic point of view under the following conditions:

1- Supervision and testimony

2- Consensual agreement to marry:  No girl/boy or woman/man can be wed against her/his will.

3- Announcement: Marriages, especially the ceremony of nikah is performed in order to announce the marriage. Therefore, nikah must be announced to everybody.

4- Mehr : Legal Share of Bride is given to the bride by the groom. It is not a condition for the nikah to be valid, but the right of mehr arises as a natural result of the nikah for the bride.

Without these it becomes void.

Comment: Fiqh books are full of examples which are in opposition of what you've quoted in 2. especially for the girl. And in accordance of the sunnah. While the qur'an just says that we the boy should get the accordance of the guardian of the girl to marry her. IMO this needs elaboration.

Comment: According to sunnah (Bukhari, 67:42, Bukhari, 67:43) and Quran (4:19, 24:33) marriage is void without a woman’s consent. There is no question in that.

Comment: None of these "evidences" supports what you claim. Try first to understand what you read before interpreting it wrongly. See also [This post about the necessity of the guardian's accordance in the qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37504/why-do-only-women-need-a-wali-for-nikah)

Comment: Our team and everyone in it has dedicated his live in studying the Quran and sunnah. One of the main conditions of marriage to be legal is “supervision”, which means that the marriage should be with the presence of an authority. This authority is someone that can protect the rights of the woman when needed. This is called Wali.
The question is about whether forced Marriages are allowed In Islam and there is no question about that. What you deem as false ‘evidence’ are Quranic verses and the sunnah. Have some respect. Jazakallah.

Comment: It seems you dedicated all these studies in vain with more or less no results. As these verses don't say anything about what you intend to proof. The wali could -theoretically-even marry the girl without her consent. And this actually is concluded from the sahih sunnah. As a girl who remains silent is considered as agreeing to the marriage.

Comment: What you’re referring to is: “The widowed woman has more right than her custodian to make a decision while the maid’s consent is mandatory.” Then he was told: “The maids are shy.” He replied: “Her silence is her consent.”This is not a matter of opinion. What you’re referring to is: “The widowed woman has more right than her custodian to make a decision while the maid’s consent is mandatory.” Then he was told: “The maids are shy and cannot speak because of their embarrassment.” He replied: “Her silence is her consent It is very clear.Muslim Nikah 66, 67, 68; Ebu Davud Nikah 26;

Comment: Yes is remaining silent a consent in reality no. This hadith has been considered as a clear evidence for the rights of a guardian to marry a girl without her consent, as as long as she doesn't clearly say no it is an agreement. Further it is/was unusual to ask underage girls about their consent. And they were married nevertheless as the guardian should know better what is good for them. Please don't waste may time with your half-kniwledge. Yourb(personal) views are not what this site is looking for.

Comment: You are posting a verse about a prostitute that has accepted Islam and was oppressed to go ahead with her (former) job as an evidence. This is a bad evidence. And dies hardly help answering the question.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5136 clearly states that a woman has to consent but that it's also agreed if she doesn't oppose and keeps silent. Maybe it was esteemed god habit in former times to keep silent. Today, in in most cultures an explicit yes is preferred and often requested by stately law.